# Kafka - Only one consumer in a consumer group gets messages even the topic has partitions

Tags: kafka

Here's my setup. I have a topic `test_topic` with partitions = 4 and replication factor = 1. I have two consumers that are on the same consumer group `test_group`.

My expectation: messages will get distributed over the consumers, that is, the consumers take turns in receiving messages.

What actually happens: only one consumer gets all messages. When you stop the consumer that is getting the messages, that's the only time the other consumer will receive the messages. When all consumers are stopped while you produce messages, the unread messages will be read as soon as you start again either consumer.

Is my understanding of partitions and consumer groups correct, or is there something wrong with my setup?

Here are the commands that I ran.

Broker

```
$ ./kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test_topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 4
```

Producer

```
$ ./kafka-console-producer.sh --topic test_topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Consumers

```
$ ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic test_topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group test_group
```

By the way, the broker process, producer process, and consumer processes are all on the same machine (you'll notice because of the "localhost"). I have already tried to set them up so that they are on different machines but same behavior.